# Как игнорировать некоторые введенные значения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, парсер

Решение почти готово,но мне нужно каким - то образом вычислять произведение не зависимо от введенных символов,например я ввожу строку : `fgh  -34  45 4` ... у меня ошибка `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fgh'`

```
arr = input("Введите список:")
arr = arr.split()
arr = list(arr)
N = len(arr)
i = j = 0  
for i in range(N):
        if int(arr[i]) > 0:
                if j == 1:
                        i1 = i
                elif j == 3:
                        i3 = i
                elif j == 6:
                        i6 = i
                        break
                j += 1
        i += 1

if i6 > 0:
        print("Индексы элементов:", i1, i3, i6)
        mult = int(arr[i1]) * int(arr[i3]) * int(arr[i6])
        print("Произведение:",mult)
else:   
        print("Произведение: 0")
```

Comment: А что, нужно игнорировать те значения, что числами не являются?

Comment: вы меня правильно поняли

Comment: Я исправил заголовок, чтобы он отражал суть вопроса.

Comment: @Noob_Prog, правильного ответа ещё нет? опишите почему ваша проблема не решена

Comment: проблема решена,сейчас у меня могут возникать вопросы по решению проблемы которые связаны с его пониманием

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте фильтрацию введенных значений, чтобы остались только числа:

```
def is_num(num: str) -> bool:
    try:
        int(num)
        return True
    except:
        return False


arr = input("Введите список:")
arr = [num for num in arr.split() if is_num(num)]
N = len(arr)
...
```

---

**PS.**

`int(...)` выбросит исключение, если к нему попадет не число

Comment: объясните пожалуйста строку кода arr = [num for num in arr.split() if is_num(num)

Comment: @Noob_Prog, это строка генерации списка и фильтрации при его создании. `for num in arr.split()` -- перебор последовательности, `num` -- значение, что попадет в список, а `if is_num(num)` -- условие добавления значения в список. Так что, этот код создает новый список, в котором будут только те значения, что соответствуют целым числам

Comment: def is_num(num):
    try:
        int(num)
        return True
    except:
        return False это конструкция которая создаёт функцию которая вернет истину если значение аргумента по типу int и перехватит исключение если не int и вернёт ложь?И ещё вопрос это конструкция выполняется в генераторе списков  arr = [num for num in arr.split() if is_num(num)] после того как мы ввели список ?

Comment: @Noob_Prog, да. Именно, в генераторе строка `arr` будет разделена на список и через `is_num` отфильтрована

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: str = "fdf 02 11 -1 -"
        from re import findall
        sum(int(number) for number in findall('-?\d+',str))

Out[1]: 12
```

Comment: Ну что-то неправильный результат-то. 321 должно быть, если сумма.

Comment: @sevnight, `isdecimal` вернет `False` для отрицательных чисел:  `'-1'.isdecimal()` # False

Comment: @gil9red, корректировка произведена, спасибо за замечание

Comment: Спасибо, мне ваш вариант нравится -- очень компактно :) кст, можно в `sum` убрать квадратные скобки -- тут они могут быть опущены -- вместо списка будет создан генератор и результат тот же

Comment: @gil9red, если убрать их, то появляется warning о том что со временем код перестанет работать `DeprecationWarning: Calling np.sum(generator) is deprecated, and in the future will give a different result. Use np.sum(np.from_iter(generator)) or the python sum builtin instead.
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.`, но так же предлагает воспользоваться стандартной суммой, так код ещё короче и numpy можно не импортировать :) внёс правку. Спасибо)

Comment: @sevnight, странное предупреждение от numpy, не ожиданное я бы сказал :) стандартный `sum` тут будут лучше, да :)

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = input("Введите список:")
l = arr.split()
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y,[int(x) for x in l if x.isdigit() or ( x.startswith("-") and x[1:].isdigit())])
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял задачу то можно так:

```
from re import findall


def mult(lst):
    if not lst:
        return 'Числовые значения не найдены'
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return int(lst[0])
    return int(lst[0]) * mult(lst[1:])


arr = ['fgh', '-34', '45', '4']

cntrl = findall('\d+', ' '.join(arr)) # '-?\d+' если нужны и отрицательные значения
print("Индексы элементов:",
      ' '.join(map(str, [i for i in range(len(arr)) if arr[i] in cntrl])) or 'Нет элементов')

print("Произведение:", mult([arr[i] for i in range(len(arr)) if arr[i] in cntrl]))
```